# Missing upvote points

Tags: support, up-votes

I read "Whats happening to my reputation" and "Missing upvote rep" and I have no idea
whats happening:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/224774/thorsten-s?tab=reputation

Looking at the reputation tab I got five upvotes for "Java Unicode String length", but only three are counted.
50 points are unlikely to hit a limit, so what is going on ?

Comment: You can flag the post to request removal of the CW status.

Comment: I must have done it accidentally (click/click). I understand the idea of "community wiki" now but find it a bit counterintuitive to punish people for good answers...

Comment: Answer has now been flagged to reverse status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer was converted to a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) post, for which upvotes do not net you any reputation.

You did so yourself in [revision 5](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15948571/revisions). You must have checked the `community wiki` checkbox to the top right of the preview box.

If you did this by accident, flag your post for moderator attention to have it removed again. The reputation for those two upvotes since you made the post CW is not recoverable, though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out revision 5.

Answer (score 5):

You have made the answer a Community Wiki post. You don't get points for any Community Wiki upvotes.

See also: [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)